# Trigger a Jenkins Build on a change to any branch, but just build once

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a rather complicated project that (for historical reasons I can't fix right now) consists of 3 semi-independent branches, plus a `master` branch.

The Build task takes place on the `master` branch, but as part of the build pulls in the latest code from the 3 independent branches.

I would like to trigger the Jenkins build whenever *any* of the branches (`master`, `a`, `b` or `c`) has changed - but when the build runs, it should only build the `master` branch.
Additionally, I don't want to build the entire job 3 times if (say) `a`, `b` and `c` have all changed since the last time Git was polled - I just need to rebuild once.

The closest solution I have found so far is to create two separate Jenkins jobs:

- Job 1 (Build) that builds the `master` branch, with no triggers
- Job 2 (Poll) that polls all four branches, and just triggers the Build job

However, this only solves the first of my requirements; with this configuration, the Build job runs several times if multiple branches have changes when the polling occurs.

Comment: So you have changes on four branches to trigger the master branch build? I wonder what is the idea behind. Usually, the best practice is per-branch-build.

Comment: As I said - I'm aware that this is not a normal or best-practice scenario; I'm just looking for a solution that will work, given these abnormal requirements.

I suppose a similar (and perhaps more normal) scenario might be a meta-project that builds from 4 different Git repositories... although in that scenario, the normal solution would be to use the artifacts from separate builds, which is not possible in this case.